# how to calculate XIRR dynamically in excel and in google sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, xls

I am trying to calculate XIRR for data that I have in the below format

```
    PurchaseDate    Script  No.ofunits  PurchNAVrate    NetAmount            ForXIRR    TotalReturn
    17/11/2014          A   2241            33              75000           -75000          96000
    8/1/2015            B   53              649             35000           -35000          43000
    14/1/2015           B   75              658             50000           -50000          61500
    14/10/2014          C   2319            32              75000           -75000          108000
    8/1/2015            D   318             109             35000           -35000          40000
    14/1/2015           D   450             110             50000           -50000          57000
    8/6/2015            D   175             114             20000           -20000          22000
```

I tried lots of different permutations and combinations but not able to calculate XIRR for each Fund. Is there a way I can do it perhaps using offset or search.
This is a dynamic list which keeps getting changed based on new funds that are bought or sold

```
Values for Fund A should be around 14%  
Values for Fund B should be around 13%
Values for Fund C should be around 21%
Values for Fund D should be around 8%
```

**Update**
Given that solution mentioned by @xor-lx was working very nicely in ms excel but not in google sheets, I have now modified the structure of my data based on @kyle advice and now I can calculate XIRR easily for each fund as a whole. Refer below

```
PurchaseDate    Today       Script  No.ofunits  PurchNAVrate    NetAmount   ForXIRR TotalReturn     XIRR
17/11/14        31/08/2016  A       2241        33              75000       -75000  96000           "=XIRR(G2:H2,A2:B2)"
                            Total for above fund                                                    "=XIRR(G2:H3,A2:B3)"
8/1/2015        31/08/2016  B       53          649             35000       -35000  43000           "=XIRR(G4:H4,A4:B4)"
14/1/2015       31/08/2016  B       75          658             50000       -50000  61500           "=XIRR(G5:H5,A5:B5)"
                            Total for above fund                                                    "=XIRR(G4:H6,A4:B6)"
14 Oct 14       31/08/2016  C       2319        32              75000       -75000  108000          "=XIRR(G7:H7,A7:B7)"
                            Total for above fund                                                    "=XIRR(G7:H8,A7:B8)"
8 Jan 15        31/08/2016  D       318         109             35000       -35000  40000           "=XIRR(G9:H9,A9:B9)"
14 Jan 15       31/08/2016  D       450         110             50000       -50000  57000           "=XIRR(G10:H10,A10:B10)"
8/6/2015        31/08/2016  D       175         114             20000       -20000  22000           "=XIRR(G11:H11,A11:B11)"
                            Total for above fund                                                    "=XIRR(G9:H12,A9:B12)"
```

Comment: Can you give us one or two manually-calculated expected results for the above dataset?

Comment: I have updated the table so that values have some meaning. Also added the expected XIRR values

Comment: If you were to do just the A fund, what would the normal XIRR() formula be?

Comment: To calculate XIRR as per excel it has to be of the below format for fund A =XIRR(-75000:96000, 17/11/2014:29/8/2016)

Comment: Where does the `29/8/2016' come from?  is it always today?

Comment: Yes..29/8/2016 represents today

Comment: the actual formula for A would be `=XIRR({-75000,96000}, {"11/17/2014","8/29/2016"})` and it returns  `14.8%`. You may need to normalize your data so that each amount has a valid date on one row to make this happen.  With your current table structure I do not believe it is possible to do what you want with a formula and may require vba.  I may be wrong but this is beyond me, sorry.

Comment: And what would the XIRR for "B" be?

Comment: I have updated the expected XIRR values

Comment: i've made a very small adjustment to my formula if you're interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your table is in `A1:G8` (with headers in row 1), and that your Fund of choice, e.g. "B", is in `J2`, array formula**:

`=XIRR(INDEX(F:G,N(IF(1,MODE.MULT(IF(B$2:B$8=J2,{1,1}*ROW(B$2:B$8))))),N(IF(1,{1,2}))),CHOOSE({1,2},INDEX(A:A,N(IF(1,MODE.MULT(IF(B$2:B$8=J2,{1,1}*ROW(B$2:B$8)))))),TODAY()))`

Copy down to give similar results for Funds in `J3`, `J4`, etc.

I tend to prefer this to set-ups involving `OFFSET`; not only is it briefer (and therefore more efficient), but also, more importantly, non-volatile.

See here for more if you're interested:

https://excelxor.com/2016/02/16/criteria-with-statistical-functions-growth-linest-logest-trend/

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: Have just read Scott Craner's comment above. Appears I may have misunderstood. If confirmed, will delete this answer.

Comment: I am not understanding your answer.  It seems it is only using the purch amounts and dates, and not the total return amounts and dates.  What kind of results are you seeing?

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld I simply used the data from the PurchaseDate and ForXIRR columns. If this is incorrect then I apologize.

Comment: Hmmm.  My thought is that he also wants to use the total return amount along with `Today` as the corresponding date.  I've posted a VBA solution with that assumption.  Hopefully he will clarify things.

Comment: I definitely want to use the total return amount. "ForXIRR" is just a negative number of "NetAmount"

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've made a small adjustment to account for that.

Comment: @XORLX I am impressed by how you constructed the requisite array out of the widely separated, and variously defined, values.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld Thanks!

Comment: @XORLX for some reason I am getting #VALUE when I copied your formula and did CTRL,SHIFT and ENTER

Comment: @Manuj And you're using the precise ranges as I specified? Or have you attempted to adapt them to meet a different worksheet layout? Also, did you definitely achieve array-entry properly according to my instructions, i.e. did the curly brackets appear around the formula?

Comment: Yes, no change in your code, This is what it looks like now {=XIRR(INDEX(F:G,N(IF(1,MODE.MULT(IF($B$2:$B$8=J2,{1,1}*ROW(B$2:B$8))))),N(IF(1,{1,2}))),CHOOSE({1,2},INDEX(A:A,N(IF(1,MODE.MULT(IF(B$2:B$8=J2,{1,1}*ROW(B$2:B$8)))))),TODAY()))}

Comment: But with the data you posted in the range I specified (A1:G8) and with the appropriate entry in J2, e.g. "B", the formula works fine.

Comment: When I click on error and do evaluate steps, it shows this XIRR({-35000,43000;-50000,61500},{42217,42612;"14/1/2015",42612}). I am certain the error is because the values for dates are showing as 42217, 42612 etc. Even if I change the format for column 1 to date, still it is not fixing.

Comment: No. Dates are correctly showing as numerics, which is how they are stored in Excel, apart from the third in the array you give ("14/1/2015"), which is clearly not a valid Excel date, but a text string representing a date. Suggest you check that entry.

Comment: Ah, ok. Good! :-)

Comment: All this effort and it seems google sheets doesnt support M‌​ODE.MULT. Any alternative to it?

Comment: Oh dear! Yes, just a bit longer and therefore resource-heavy. Added to the post.

Comment: I tried but I am getting an error on google sheets "In XIRR evaluation, the value array must include positive and negative numbers."  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sL9HvIB7GE-2hYSF5GAz5B8D5zuy6plhB1yqKLPdOZU/edit#gid=0

Comment: And you know how to enter an array formula equivalently in Google Sheets? Afraid I don't know much about Sheets...

Comment: same ctrl shift and enter. Instead of curly brackets for array formula, it seems google puts "=ArrayFormula" in the beginning

Comment: And I take it that you do have positive and negative numbers in the array being passed? Failing that, is there a way to debug in Sheets, similar to Evaluate Formula in Excel?

Comment: Exact same data as tried above..no change. No idea on how to debug in google sheets

Comment: Neither have I, I'm afraid.

Comment: Then I ask another question on stackoverflow :) , this time on why this particular function doesnt work on google sheets. Thanks for your support and patience

Comment: Ok, but are you sure you know precisely which function is at fault?

Comment: Nope. But as a start I am blaming arrayformula http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39228169/why-does-a-specific-arrayformula-not-work-in-google-sheets-but-works-fine-in-exc

Comment: Have deleted the suggested Google Sheets version in light of the fact that that too does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

`XIRR` requires two arrays of arguments -- values and dates (with an optional third "guess" argument).  To try to stitch together those arrays from non-contiguous ranges of purchase dates, total returns, purchase amounts, and a number of "today's dates" would be quite a challenge for an Excel formula.  Hence I provide a User Defined Function written in VBA.

The arguments for the function are the fund or script (`sFund`) and your data table range laid out as you have in your example above.

As suggested in one of your comments, I used `TODAY` as the date corresponding to the `Total Return` column.  Easily changed if that is not the case.

Also, note that I did not use the "forXIRR" column, rather I just used the negative of the `NetAmount` column.  If you delete the `forXIRR` column, you will need to change the reference to `.TotalReturn`

I created a custom Class in order to make things a bit more understandable.

After you insert the Class Module, you must rename it `cFUND`

### Class Module

```
Option Explicit
'Rename cFUND

Private pFund As String

Private pPurchDt As Date
Private pPurchDts As Collection

Private pPurchAmt As Double
Private pPurchAmts As Collection

Private pTotalReturn As Double
Private pTotalReturns As Collection

Public Property Get Fund() As String
    Fund = pFund
End Property
Public Property Let Fund(Value As String)
    pFund = Value
End Property

Public Property Get PurchDt() As Date
    PurchDt = pPurchDt
End Property
Public Property Let PurchDt(Value As Date)
    pPurchDt = Value
End Property
Public Function ADDPurchDt(Value As Date)
    pPurchDts.Add Value
End Function
Public Property Get PurchDts() As Collection
    Set PurchDts = pPurchDts
End Property

Public Property Get PurchAmt() As Double
    PurchAmt = pPurchAmt
End Property
Public Property Let PurchAmt(Value As Double)
    pPurchAmt = Value
End Property
Public Function ADDPurchAmt(Value As Double)
    pPurchAmts.Add Value
End Function
Public Property Get PurchAmts() As Collection
    Set PurchAmts = pPurchAmts
End Property

Public Property Get TotalReturn() As Double
    TotalReturn = pTotalReturn
End Property
Public Property Let TotalReturn(Value As Double)
    pTotalReturn = Value
End Property
Public Function ADDTotalReturn(Value As Double)
    pTotalReturns.Add Value
End Function
Public Property Get TotalReturns() As Collection
    Set TotalReturns = pTotalReturns
End Property

Public Function CalcXIRR()
    Dim v, d, w
    Dim I As Long
    With Me
        ReDim d(.PurchDts.Count * 2 - 1)
        ReDim v(UBound(d))

        I = 0
        For Each w In .PurchAmts
            v(I) = w
            I = I + 1
        Next w
        For Each w In .TotalReturns
            v(I) = w
            I = I + 1
        Next w

        I = 0
        For Each w In .PurchDts
            d(I) = w
            I = I + 1
        Next w
        Do Until I > UBound(d)
            d(I) = Date
            I = I + 1
        Loop
    End With

    CalcXIRR = WorksheetFunction.XIRR(v, d)
End Function
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pPurchDts = New Collection
    Set pPurchAmts = New Collection
    Set pTotalReturns = New Collection
End Sub
```

### Regular Module

```
Option Explicit
Function fundXIRR(sFund As String, rTable As Range) As Double
    Dim vSrc As Variant
    Dim cF As cFUND
    Dim I As Long

vSrc = rTable

Set cF = New cFUND
For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    If vSrc(I, 2) = sFund Then
        With cF
            .PurchDt = vSrc(I, 1)
            .ADDPurchDt .PurchDt
            .Fund = vSrc(I, 2)
            .PurchAmt = -vSrc(I, 5)
            .ADDPurchAmt .PurchAmt
            .TotalReturn = vSrc(I, 7)
            .ADDTotalReturn .TotalReturn
        End With
    End If
Next I

fundXIRR = cF.CalcXIRR

End Function
```

---

Given your data above, `XIRR` for `B` would be calculated as:

```
XIRR({-35000;-50000;43000;61500},{"1/8/2015";"1/14/2015";"8/29/2016";"8/29/2016"}
```

Here are the results for your data above:

[image]

Comment: I tried your example but I am getting a little different values `A 0.148200816
B 0.157973212
C 0.21411528
D 0.09769842`.  Side questions(Because I am not good with VBA(First time using it today)) - How do I change the value for TODAY and also if I remove `ForXIRR` then what do I need to change for `.TotalReturn`

Comment: @Manuj The difference for `A` and `C` is because of different `TODAY`'s.  I cannot explain the differences for `B` and `D`.  Your results do not seem possible for the values you show in the table, since none of the single line XIRR's are as high.

Comment: @Manuj To change `TODAY` you change the part where I insert `DATE` into the `d` array in the Class Module.  And if you change the arrangement of Columns, you need to change the arguments for `vSrc` to return the proper column.  See Chip Pearson's article: [VBA Arrays And Worksheet Ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx) for a detailed explanation of what is happening with `vSrc`.

Comment: @Manuj Look also at XOR's formula.  His returns the same results as mine, but avoids using VBA.  You would still need to explain the differences for the Funds with multiple investments.

Comment: For Fund B, If I do =fundXIRR(E15,$A$1:$G$8) then I get 0.157973212. If I do =fundXIRR(B3,A3:G4), then however I get the right answer. I will try XOR's answer also in a test sheet now. E15 and B3 are B just to clarify :)

Comment: @Manuj Both of those formulas are returning the wrong answer..  The first for reasons I don't understand; the second is incorrect as it is only returning the answer for the second investment in `B`, and not for both investments.  Upload a copy of your workbook that demonstrates the problem, so that I can see what the issue is.

Comment: I think i found out the reason for the issue..In the first column PurchaseDate the dates were not in the right format for some reason. When I changed the dates to the right format, I am getting 0.134719795..

Comment: @Manuj Yes, VBA will interpret improperly formatted date strings in unpredictable ways.

Comment: @Manuj Actually, when I copied your table, I assumed all of the dates were in `DMY` format since some of them clearly had to be.  And that is how the VBA code would have interpreted them.  If, in fact `8/1/2015` was really in `MDY` format, that explains the difference for the `B` calculation.

Comment: Google sheets does not like XOR's solution so for now it looks like only way to do it is through the Macros way in google sheets. Is there a way that the above VBA code can be run in google sheets?

Comment: @Manuj not that I am aware of. I think Google Sheets uses a Java like language and I'm not aware of any translator.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume based on your table that the date is column A, the fund (or "Script") is column B and the "ForXIRR" is column F. The below will do it for you:

```
{=XIRR(IF(B:B="A",F:F,0),IF(B:B="A",A:A,0))}
```

Make sure you enter this with `Shift + Ctrl + Enter` since it is an array formula.

Note: The above will calculate for "A", but substitute that part of the formula for any other fund, or use a cell reference to calculate for others.

EDIT:

I realized the above will only work for the first letter in the sequence, please use below, and again, adjust the `"B"` to whatever you need. This will work for any of the letters present. Also, adjust all the ranges to match your needs, I only did rows 1:10 for my test purposes. The below adjusts the start of the range so it is always the first value for whichever fund is input (ie "A", "B", "C") to allow this to calculate. Without this change, the above will always start with a zero unless it is the first in the list ("A" in the OPs example), and XIRR only calculates with a negative number as the first value.

```
=XIRR(IF(OFFSET($B$1:$B$10,MATCH("B",$B$1:$B$10,0)-1,0,ROWS($B$1:$B$10)-MATCH("B",$B$1:$B$10,0)+1,1)="B",OFFSET($F$1:$F$10,MATCH("B",$B$1:$B$10,0)-1,0,ROWS($B$1:$B$10)-MATCH("B",$B$1:$B$10,0)+1,1),0),IF(OFFSET($B$1:$B$10,MATCH("B",B1:B10,0)-1,0,ROWS($B$1:$B$10)-MATCH("B",$B$1:$B$10,0)+1,1)="B",OFFSET($A$1:$A$10,MATCH("B",$B$1:$B$10,0)-1,0,ROWS($B$1:$B$10)-MATCH("B",$B$1:$B$10,0)+1,1),0))
```

Comment: Unless the OP actually has data extending all the way down to row 1048576, the use of entire column references within an array formula is a disastrous idea.

Comment: More importantly, with XIRR, I don't think that using zero values for any entries which don't meet the criteria is equivalent to excluding them.

Comment: For XIRR it is, because you feed a date of 0 as well, so it isn't included in the calc. If the OP gave more detail, I would have limited the column to however they specified.

Comment: How can that work where your formula only looks at a single value and a single date?  For `A`, your formula reduces to something like `=XIRR({-75000;0;0;0;0....},{41960;0;0;0;0....})`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, because I'm assuming the OP isn't looking to calc the XIRR of a single value, and thus assume the data in the post is for structural purposes only, and not to give a complete idea (inferred because the OP knows what XIRR they are looking for, and that takes more than one number).

Comment: That may be, but since all of your values are coming from Column F, they will all be negative, and result in a `#NUM` error

Comment: That column is a "cash impact" meaning how the transaction affects the fund in question. Meaning what we see above are "buys" (cash out) and the rest will be "sells" or cash in. Maybe I'm doing a lot of assuming, but I assume the OP works at an investment firm and understands how returns work, and how XIRR works (ie needs a negative number followed by positives).

Comment: The numeric data includes the total return column, see the comments above on how A should be calculated.  And If it was only the one column you would not put the dates in the array, but include all of them as 0 on any date does not effect the XIRR. `=XIRR({-75000,0,96000}, {"11/17/2014","1/1/2015","8/29/2016"})` returns the same as `=XIRR({-75000,96000}, {"11/17/2014","8/29/2016"})`

Comment: then for B it would be something like `=XIRR({-35000,43000,-50000,61500},{"1/8/2015","1/13/2015","1/14/2015","8/29/2016"})` with the `"1/13/2015"` being a guess on the date.  Without the normalization of the data where then XIRR column and Total Return column with the proper dates it is hard to find a formula that would work.  XIRR is made for two arrays, a group of numbers and a group of dates.  The OP has split the numbers into two groups with one set of dates that do not correlate with the second group of numbers.

Comment: @Kyle  Well, using either of your formulas on my copy of the OP's data returns a `#NUM!` error.  I really don't see how it will create two arrays with matching values and dates.  And from the OP's comment, I believe he wants "today" for the date corresponding with his Total Return column, in calculating XIRR.

Comment: @ScottCraner I see you have a different idea of what date should match the Total Return column than I do.  I hope the OP will clarify.

Comment: @ScottCraner I must have misunderstood as well. As for your comment "And If it was only the one column you would not put the dates in the array, but include all of them as 0 on any date does not effect the XIRR" that is exactly the mistake I made in my first answer, that is not the case when the first value ends up being zero. The first value must be a negative, which is why I posted an edited answer.

Comment: OP ie me is commenting to clarify some questions..I dont work in an investment firrm(And that is a good thing). I am an engineer trying to create my own portfolio manager in excel. The XIRR will be calculated where I have a single transaction in a Fund (ie XIRR of a single value to be calculated)  as well as for multiple buys of Funds. I understand that for XIRR there has to be negative numbers and the positive number that is why ForXIRR was created for negative numbers and total return for current value for each transaction. Also date for Total return is always Today()

Comment: @Manuj It may be worthwhile to change your structure if you are not married to it. I would suggest having all buys and sells in the same column then. As many have stated, `XIRR` takes two arrays, which are easier to pass to the function when the data is structured such that all cash flows are in one column.

Comment: The total return is not a sell. It is the value of investment as on today and is calculated through additional functions. As there are multiple entries that i have to add frequently, having all the cash flows in a single column will be cumbersome to manage as there will be others who will be updating it also

Comment: I would argue that most aspects of this are cumbersome as well.

Comment: As per your advice, I have now modified the data and I am now able to get XIRR values for each of the funds :)