# Why does a specific arrayformula not work in google sheets but works fine in excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, array-formulas

This is in continuation to [how to calculate XIRR dynamically in excel and in google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39211880/how-to-calculate-xirr-dynamically-in-excel)

The proposed array formula** solution (mentioned below) works perfectly fine in excel

> =XIRR(INDEX(F:G,N(IF(1,SMALL(IF(B$2:B$8=J2,ROW(B$2:B$8)),ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,COUNTIF(B$2:B$8,J2)))))),N(IF(1,{1,2}))),CHOOSE({1,2},INDEX(A:A,N(IF(1,SMALL(IF(B$2:B$8=J2,ROW(B$2:B$8)),ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,COUNTIF(B$2:B$8,J2))))))),TODAY()))

but the same solution refuses to work in google sheets with the error

> In XIRR evaluation, the value array must include positive and negative numbers.

Any idea why this is not working in google sheets and how to make it work?

Source data

```
    PurchaseDate    Script  No.ofunits  PurchNAVrate    NetAmount            ForXIRR    TotalReturn
    17/11/2014          A   2241            33              75000           -75000          96000
    8/1/2015            B   53              649             35000           -35000          43000
    14/1/2015           B   75              658             50000           -50000          61500
    14/10/2014          C   2319            32              75000           -75000          108000
    8/1/2015            D   318             109             35000           -35000          40000
    14/1/2015           D   450             110             50000           -50000          57000
    8/6/2015            D   175             114             20000           -20000          22000



Values for Fund A should be around 14%  
Values for Fund B should be around 13%
Values for Fund C should be around 21%
Values for Fund D should be around 8%
```

Comment: Specific answer to your question seems to be "because google sheets in not excel and vice-versa"  ;-)

Answer (score -1):

It appears that the the constructions which allow us to generate an array of returns from `INDEX`, i.e.:

`N(IF(1,,,`

or

`N(INDEX(,,,`

are valid in Excel but not in Google Sheets, in the latter both resolving to just a single (i.e. the first) element in the array passed.

For example, in Excel, the following:

`=SUM(INDEX(A1:A10,N(IF(1,{1,2,7}))))`

or:

`=SUM(INDEX(A1:A10,N(INDEX({1,2,7},))))`

will sum the values in `A1`, `A2` and `A7`, though in Google Sheets both will sum only the value in `A1`.

I do not know enough about Google Sheets to know why this is the case. It may be possible to reconstruct my formula using the volatile `OFFSET`. I will have a look and get back to you.

Update: It appears that even an `OFFSET`-based solution, i.e.:

`=XIRR(N(OFFSET(F2,SMALL(IF(B$2:B$8=J2,ROW(B$2:B$8)-MIN(ROW(B$2:B$8))),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTIF(B$2:B$8,J2)))),{0,1})),CHOOSE({1,2},N(OFFSET(A2,SMALL(IF(B$2:B$8=J2,ROW(B$2:B$8)-MIN(ROW(B$2:B$8))),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTIF(B$2:B$8,J2)))),{0,1})),TODAY()))`

is not possible. Again, it works fine in Excel but not in Google Sheets, for reasons similar to those given above (the arrays passed to `OFFSET` do not resolve as required).

I think this requires an explanation by someone well-versed in Google Sheets.

References:

https://excelxor.com/2014/09/05/index-returning-an-array-of-values/

Regards